# get all the other user names where user=1 exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following "tblA" and "tblB" table:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  sender varchar(255),
  receiver varchar(255),
  msg varchar(255),
  date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  sno varchar(255),
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver, msg,date) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:19:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09'),
('3', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:24:09'),
('3', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:25:19'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '3', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '3', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09'),
('1', '4', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('1', '5', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '6', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '7', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('8', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09');


INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');
```

How to get all rows with user : `1`existing along with the name of sender/receiver which is not`1`   (ie:`Aa`)

Comment: user is me in this case sno=1 and name=`Aa`

Comment: So you want users that have not sent or received any messages?

Comment: no I want all the rows which has 1 (me) in it and with the name of the person who is other than me .It could be receiver or sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get the unique list:

```
select distinct b.name
from tblA a join
     tblB b
     on b.id in (a.sender, a.receiver) and
        ((b.id <> 1 and (a.sender = 1 or a.receiver = 1)) or
         (a.sender = 1 and a.receiver = 1)
        );
```

Comment: Hello Sir I was about to post the link to you .Thanks for looking into it .http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49f8c/28 .This is showing all rows even without 1 in it .

Comment: this query is excluding the row where both sender and receiver is 1 .I would like to include that too.How do I do that ? Apart from that its correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ta.*, tb.name
FROM tablA ta, tablB tb WHERE (ta.sender = tb.sno OR ta.receiver = tb.sno)
                        AND tb.sno <> 1
```